# Windows 7 won't boot after hibernation

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have an ASUS laptop K55VM, and what happened to me was that I closed the lid, and the computer went to hibernation. After I started the computer again, it took quite some time to load to windows login screen, and after that, the loading screen poped up and stayed there a little. But after that, the screen wen't pitch black and it didn't go from there.

I then restarted the computer and it failed to boot everytime. What happened was that it gave me an option to run windows normally or run the recovery mode. It didn't matter what option I chose, it started the recovery every time. After the recovery was finnished, I checked the log and somehow, the disk drive letters were mixed up. I have my windows installed on C:/windows, and the log file said there was no operating systems found on D:/windows.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this issue, maybe somehow change the drive letters using linux(I also have linux set to dual boot and linux works fine)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a chance of file missing or file corruption in the Operating System. Insert the OS Disk and select the repair option on the install window do repairing the restart the computer.

Comment: I will try that and report the results. Thank you.

Comment: It didn't work. I also tried to rebuild bcd in recovery console doing bootrec /rebuildbcd, and it said it found 0 installations of windows....wich is terrifying. I don't know what else to do :S

Comment: during repair, will that detects windows-7 OS installed partition?

Comment: It detects installation on D:/Windows

Comment: But my windows is on C:

Comment: how do you know it is in c:  ?

Comment: If you install os on d: the get inside the OS.. if you open my computer, it will shows OS installed Drive as c: